# How do I set a variable based on the value in the payload?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

How do I set a variable (using set variable transformer) based on the value in the payload ? where payload is of json format.

if payload.segmentation = local, then value of variable should be "material_reg"

if payload.segmentation = network, then value of variable should be "material"

Comment: What mule runtime is this?

Comment: Run time 4.2.2.   Studio 7.41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [pattern matching](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-pattern-matching):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.segmentation match {
 case "local" -> "material_reg"
 case "network" -> "material"
}
```

Or just [if/else clauses](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-flow-control):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
if (payload.segmentation == "local") 
    "material_reg"
else 
    if (payload.segmentation == "network") 
        "material" 
    else 
        ""
```

Note that I'm using `application/json` as output but I think `application/java` or even `text/plain` would work for you since you just want a String variable.

Comment: I tried those, but I am getting "Auto-Coercing type.." errors. Couldn't run after deploying as well.

Comment: These solutions should work, if they don't for you I would suggest adding an example of your payload and/or the xml of your flow